# How to I get tab_model to display properly in Rmarkdown PDF?

Tags: r, r-markdown, sjplot

I realize this is probably quite simple, but I have looked and can't find an example of how to use sjPlot::tab_model in an Rmarkdown document sent to PDF.

Here is reproducible code:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Me"
date: "2020/12/6"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(sjPlot)
````

### A table

```
tab_model(lm(mpg~cyl, data=mtcars))
```

And what I get looks something like this:

A table
tab_model(lm(mpg~cyl, data=mtcars))
mpg
Predictors
Estimates
CI
p
(Intercept)
37.88
33.65 – 42.12
<0.001
cyl
-2.88
-3.53 – -2.22
<0.001
Observations
32
R2 / R2 adjusted

Comment: It isn't clear what your problem is. What should your output look like? Is the output currently only a string of words not formatted in any kind of table?

Comment: @Dylan_Gomes Exactly, the output is just text, not a formatted table.

Comment: Just created a function to create tex and pdf versions of sjPlot::tab_model(): https://github.com/gorkang/html2latex/

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to save the html within the `tab_model` function and then read it into the Rmd doc [Include HTML files in R Markdown file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524238/include-html-files-in-r-markdown-file).

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(sjPlot)
```

```{r plot}

tab_model(lm(mpg~cyl, data=mtcars),file="test.html")

```


```{r, echo=FALSE}
htmltools::includeHTML("test.html")
```
````

But I get the same problem, which makes me think there is some option for formatting html tables in Rmd, but I can't seem to find a solution.

There is a related post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33182503/9096420, but tab_model doesn't work well with the code there, because it requires a data frame.

I think there is a bit of a hack that works, but isn't ideal. You can save the output as a png and then include it in the Rmd doc https://stackoverflow.com/a/25167279/9096420.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Dylan Gomes"
date: "12/7/2020"
output: pdf_document
---
![Caption for the picture.](test.png) ## this file 'test.png' needs to be in the working directory.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known issue, and the creator of the package (Daniel) responded here: https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues/712

In the meantime, I ended up creating a couple functions to help out.

Please see the Github repo https://github.com/gorkang/html2latex/.

In the repo you can find an example.Rmd file with step-by-step instructions. It works in a Ubuntu 20.04 system.